# JQuery Equal to or Contains String Value did not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to replace text in `a anchor tag` by using JQuery or JavaScript.

I have written below code but unfortunately, It does not work for me.

```
  var signout_txt = $('.myt-nluseri-info2 a').text().trim();
  var singout_ttt = signout_txt.toString();
  if(singout_ttt == "Sign Out" || singout_ttt == "SIGN OUT") {
     alert(4567);
     $('.myt-nluseri-info2 a').replace("Log Out");
  }
```

Can anyone help how to solve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: `$('.myt-nluseri-info2 a').text("Log Out");`

Comment: my if condition does not work ?

Comment: It's work. See fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/syfukxv0/